# Action,ActionListener,Set propertyListener .Which will be fired first?

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using Jdeveloper 11.1.2.0.0
I have a jsf page in which there is a input text field and a command button.
The command button`s work is to just commit.
But i have two setPropertyListener on the command button that sets the value of two mandatory attributes of that VO.
So which will be fired first?
Action or setPropertyListener.

Answer (score 1):

ActionListener fires before Action. SetProperty fires before ActionListener.
Easy to test. Write a simple Java Backing Bean and print a value that is changed by the SetProperty Listener. Then Print in ActionListener and Action and see what the value is and the order of the print statements.
This [post](http://tompeez.wordpress.com/tag/afsetpropertylistener/) may help. And [this](http://lspatil25.blogspot.com/2012/04/identifying-type-of-adf-set-property.html). And [this](https://tompeez.wordpress.com/tag/setpropertylistener/).

Answer (score 0):

Order of calls made: SetPropertyListener,ActionListener,Action